# Xceed DocX How to create an index in a generated word document

Tags: c#, xceed, novacode-docx

I'm using Xceed in C# .Net

I can't find any documentation on how to create an index with Xceed/DocX. 
Is it even possible to do in the first place?

I'd like to create one from scratch, because I'm not using a template.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to table of content>?
This will instamagically add the table of content and the page numbers. for all the headings in your document.

```
xceedDocxHelper.InsertTableOfContents("Table of Content", TableOfContentsSwitches.O | 
TableOfContentsSwitches.U | TableOfContentsSwitches.Z | 
TableOfContentsSwitches.H);
```